# How to set maximum number of wildcard characters in a regex?

Tags: regex

I have a directory with a bunch of XMLs, some of which contain two lines like this:

```
31/02/2014 11:15 | Bla Bla Bla Target1 Bla Bla Bla
31/02/2014 11:15 | Bla Bla Target 2 Bla Bla Bla Bla
```

The important thing is I find the lines that contain Target1 and Target2. These two lines will always be next to each other but the Bla's can be different each time, but probably never any more than 100 characters.

***So what I'm looking for is something like:***

```
Target1[Greedy match (Maximum 100)]Target2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Target1 and Target2 will be in consecutive lines, you can check for one newline at the middle of your regex:

```
(Target1.{1,100}[\n\r].{1,100}Target2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `{n,m}` quantifier to make upper or lower bounds on the amount of token matches, e.g. `{0,100}` will match at least 0 but at most 100 instances.

But I guess that's not your *actual* problem. You probably just want to see whether there is exactly one line break between `Target1` and `Target2`:

```
Target1[^\r\n]*\r?\n[^\r\n]*Target2
```

Comment: You could replace `[^\r\n]*` with `.*`

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
Target1(?:\n|.){1,100}Target2
```

Demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/zZ9qI6)